# Use local user login as password protection in python

Tags: python, windows, authentication, encryption

I have some python (2.7) code, that connects to a DB and therefore stores the connection credentials as plaintext, which is unsecure and therefore I want to encrypt it. The code has to be run under a distinct windows user name, which has further rights (file IO etc.). The code should run unattended, so providing a password at run-time is unfeasible. I would like to use the windows user login, to authenticate the code (As in: If user 'abc' is logged in, use his credentials to decrypt the DB credentials.).
Is this possible?

Bonus question: Is there a cross-plattform method to use user authentication for this kind of tasks?

Answer (score 1):

you could read the credentials from a file that only the user can access...

or you could use [DPAPI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995355.aspx)

Comment: Specifically for credentials you'd use the [Credential API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374731(v=vs.85).aspx#credentials_management_functions) (e.g. `CredRead`). In Python you can use PyWin32's [`win32cred`](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/3.4/pywin32/win32cred.html) module. The user's credential vault is secured using DPAPI, plus the Control Panel has a convenient app to manage credentials.